# Do swfupload have any issues with authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swfupload

Do swfupload have any issues with authentication in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but there is a workaround:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190804195152/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx)